# Implementing feature hashing using guava

Tags: java, hashcode, guava

I am trying to implement [feature hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing) in Java. For this I am trying to use Hashing functions from guava.

This is how I am doing it now:

```
//seed is any integer.
HashFunction hf = Hashing.murmur3_32(seed); 

//key is the input int and hd is the hashed dimension.
int hash = Hashing.consistentHash(hf.hashInt(key), hd);
```

I have another method for sign, not shown in this question.

To measure the performance, I am doing something like below:

```
int min = 0, max = 2000000, sampleSize = 3000000;
int[] hds = { 2000, 5000, 6000, 10000, 20000, 500000, 1000000, 2000000 };

List<Double> guavaCollisons = new ArrayList<>();

UniformIntegerDistribution runif = new UniformIntegerDistribution(min, max);

Arrays.stream(hds)
        .forEach(hd -> {
            int seed = runif.sample();

            HashFunction hf = Hashing.murmur3_32(seed);

            Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> guava = new HashMap<>();

            Arrays.stream(runif.sample(sampleSize))
                    .forEach(key -> {

                        int guavaHash = Hashing.consistentHash(hf.hashInt(key), hd);

                        if (!guava.containsKey(guavaHash))
                            guava.put(guavaHash, new HashSet<Integer>());

                        guava.get(guavaHash).add(key);
                    });

            double guavaCollisionHd = guava.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .mapToInt(entry -> entry.getValue()
                            .size())
                    .average()
                    .getAsDouble();

            guavaCollisons.add(guavaCollisionHd);

            System.out.println("Available buckets = " + hd 
                + ",  unutilized = " + (hd - guava.keySet().size())
                + ", guava collision = " + guavaCollisionHd);
        });

double guavaCollision = Stats.meanOf(guavaCollisons);
System.out.println("Average collision = " + guavaCollision);
```

My questions are:

1. Is this a correct way to implement the 'hash' part of feature hashing?
2. Is this a correct way to measure the collision rate of the hashing technique?

Comment: If you are downvoting, please provide reason; otherwise I can't improve the quality of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified code:

```
List<Double> guavaCollisions = Arrays.stream(hashDimensions)
    .map(dimension -> {
        HashFunction hashFunction = Hashing.murmur3_32(runif.sample());
        Map<Integer, Long> guavaCounts = Arrays.stream(runif.sample(sampleSize))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(key -> Hashing.consistentHash(hashFunction.hashInt(key), dimension),
                 Collectors.counting());
        return guavaCounts.values().stream().mapToLong(id -> id).average().getAsDouble();
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Reasoning:

- Inlined the `seed`. Keeping the `seed` variable there isn't necessary since we don't use it anymore, not even in the logging-statement.
- Used `collect` instead of `forEach(el -> collection.add(el))` to create Collections which is more idiomatic.
- Dropped the `Set<Integer>` from the `Map`, since we don't actually ever use the Integers we keep in memory here, but instead only want the number of unique integers. (Note that currently I don't check for uniqueness, which means the semantics changed)
- Simplified the calculation of `average` from `guavaCounts` by not streaming the entry-set and then mapping to value, which could be simplified by using `Entry::getValue`, but directly streaming the `values()`.
- Dropped the `System.out` because it's incredibly slow in comparison, a side-effect that shouldn't be happening in a `Stream` and doesn't add viable information to the "final" result of the code.
- Renamed `hds`, `hd` and `hf` because shortening names is pointless. I'd have preferred to also rename `runif`, but didn't find a better name, which would remain succinct.